# Does MessageBox.show() in c# and Report.info() in ranorex have the same functionality..?

Tags: c#, ranorex

I am Using the following code to read a excel file by using ranorex tool. i want to know whether messageBox.Show() and Report.Info() has the same functionality as i have to replace the c# attributes with ranorex.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            Excel.Range range ;

            string str;
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
                {
                    str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2 ;
                    MessageBox.Show(str);
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to know whether messageBox.Show() and Report.Info() has the same functionality

No they don't.

One is for displaying a *model message box* on screen; the other is for placing information into a Ranorex *report file* for viewing later.

Ranorex:

> Logs an info-level message, using the default category.

It's not necessary to convert them if you don't want. You can use Ranorex's [PopupWatcher](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/T_Ranorex_PopupWatcher.htm) to be on the lookout for such dialogs and automatically click them.

[Tell me more...](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/M_Ranorex_Report_Info.htm)

Comment: I don't think you can use Ranorex to close a popup that is generated by the Ranorex runner itself!!!  As mentioned, messagebox.show() is _modal_ thus Ranorex runner will be blocked on the message box show function until the OK button is clicked.  I am not sure the popup watcher would work in this condition.  Anyway, I've had bad experience with popup watcher and would not use them.  They did not seem to work consistently and I avoid them, for now...

Comment: @Sup3rHugh Incorrect. OP is using Winforms namespace

Comment: @Sup3rHugh MessageBox is WinForms.  You would not be using Ranorex to display modal windows that was not produced by the AUT in the first place during an automation run.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the code example was from the automated test, not the AUT.

Comment: @Sup3rHugh Not a problem Hugh.  Have a fine weekend. :)